# How to hide a button control in ASP.net when I click in any space of the webform in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hide, webforms

I have a button in my webform, and what I want to do is to hide it when I click on any space of my webform. Is this possible? I am using VB.net for the code.

Comment: What will trigger the button becoming visible again?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use javascript. If you're using jQuery, they have a simple [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function.